# Pynthon | random.randint | invalid type promontion | when np.hstack or np.append

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray

I'm trying to add to an empty np array the result of a `np.random.randint`.
To add the result, I have tried with `np.append`, `np.hstack`, but in any case always I take an "invalid type promotion".
Thanks for the help.

```
for i in range(10):
    print("Choose random row from a 2D array")
    randomRow = np.random.randint(0,6,size=2)
    a2 = np.hstack((a2, a1[randomRow[0],:]))
```

Comment: What's `a2`?  There isn't such a thing as an "empty np array", at least not in the same sense as a list `[]`.  Repeated `np.append` or `np.hstack` is not recommended - it is slow and hard to do right.

Comment: a2, a1 are lists

Comment: If `a1` is a list, this indexing won't work: `a1[randomRow[0],:]`.  That indexing only works for a 2d `numpy` array.